# Silverlight File Upload not working on server side

Tags: c#, silverlight, file-upload

I made File Upload following this tutorial, but for some reason my server side is not working at all.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/FileUploadsilverlight03182009030537AM/FileUploadsilverlight.aspx

Comment: `Not working at all` is not a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: Server side service is not responding at all, what could be problem, code is same as in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, but the code includes a line:

```
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:3840/receiver.ashx");
```

For this to work in your project, you'll have to change the 3840 to the port number that Visual Studio creates for you when you debug your project. Otherwise you're pointing at a port that isn't listening for anything. Check the URL of the test page to find the correct number.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I changed port number to port number that my debug project has, but it still doesn't work, is there any way to debug this problem?

Comment: I have two projects inside my solution other is silverlight app and other is C# server side projet, is there any config that could be wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the server side? Set a breakpoint on the receiver entry point and see if it hits it. If it does, then you should find out why it's not working. If it doesn't, then the problem is with the way you're connecting from the Silverlight. Are you checking the e.Error returned in the handler for the upload? Or does it not return at all?